# Celery sometimes gives all jobs to one worker

Tags: python, multithreading, celery

we have a system that runs a bunch of long tasks (sometimes 10 minutes long) and sometimes (I can't yet reproduce it, but I see it in logs) celery behaves like this (I present a sample "timeline" of things that happen):

- all workers are free
- a lot of jobs is sent to celery
- celery spreads work equally between workers
- celery autoscales to accommodate new jobs
- all (or almost all) jobs end properly
- celery assigns ALL NEW jobs to one worker
- jobs get delayed waiting for one overworked worker while all other workers are idle
- after overworked worker is killed by celery everything returns to normal

Because of that, some jobs get delayed by, sometimes, even half an hour.

This is how we run celery:

```
celery -A application worker -l INFO --autoscale=100,12

celery -A application beat -l INFO
```

we use supervisor to run everything. Celery broker is RabbitMQ.

What can be the cause of this behavior and how to avoid this?

Thanks!

Comment: I have seen this happen on my systems as well.  I don't believe there is any way directly to fix this, however, If you have tasks that are that long running you may want to set the prefetch_multiplier setting on celery much lower.  This will cause fewer Jobs to end up on a worker at a given time.

Comment: @user2097159 you were right, setting prefetch_multiplier to 1 seems to fix the problem on long runners. Thanks!